# Geometry-type of triangle

Tags: geometry

I cannot figure out what type of triangle such that the perpendicular bisector of each of exactly 2 of the sides passes through the opposite vertex. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Such triangle does not exist because one perpendicular bisector passing through the opposite vertex means it is a isosceles triangle, so two of such sides means it is equilateral which implies the third side also has this property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For "exactly 1..." and "exactly 3", I know they are isosceles and equilateral. For "exactly 2.." I thought there is no type of it as what you said. Thanks for confirming my thought.